# How to avoid adding URL to browser history on submit

Tags: back-button, browser-history

We have a sales flow that at a certain point redirects the user to an external secure page.
This is done calling an internal page with some logic to prepares the request for the external page and then submits the data.
When the user is in the external page, if he clicks the back button will go to our "dummy" page only to be redirected again to the external page.

The user should quickly click twice to get to the correct page.

Is there any way to avoid that? Like not adding the "dummy" page to the history?
I cannot change the external page.

I have read about window.location.replace but in this case I am submitting a form, not redirecting the page.

Comment: Back button is a head ache :) can't you check the referral url and then redirect back/submit form accordingly?

Comment: Unfortunately this works only when a page links to the other, not when hitting the back button.

Comment: The back button is something users expect to work in a certain way. Trying to monkey with it is going to be counter-productive. If the user clicks the back button, are they prompted to repost their data, or was that already posted to your internal page?

Comment: They are not prompted to post anything, they just go back to the previous step where they can amend the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to this but you could attach a `history.pushState()` to the `onSubmit` event on the interim page which injects the previous page in front.

So where your original flow was

```
Startpage (S) -> Interim page (I) -> External page (E)
```

The history version would be

```
S -> I -> S* -> E
```

Where `S*` is the url of `S` which has been inserted with `pushState()`

Obviously the better option would be to not have the interim page - maybe it would be better spending the effort on setting up S to do everything you need it to?